# A simple number guessing program in php using HTML Form

Tags: php, forms

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Guessing Game</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome to my guessing game</h1>
    <form action="" method="GET">
      <label for="numinput">Enter your number</label>
      <input type="text" name="numinput">
      <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>

<?php
$num = $_GET['numinput'];
if (!isset($_GET['num'])) {
  echo("Missing Guess Parameter");
} elseif ( strlen($_GET['num']) <60){
  echo ("Your guess is too short");
} elseif ( !is_numeric($_GET['num'])){
  echo("Your guess is not a number");
} elseif ($_GET['num'] > 60){
  echo ("Your guess is too high");
} else {
  echo ("Congratulations - You are right");
}
?>
</html>
```

My goal is to create a simple number guessing game using $_GET in php
Output: "Missing Guess Parameter" despite i provide any number in the input. Also, I couldn't understand whether to get the user provided data from submit of the textbox.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `$num` instead of `$_GET['num']` after the variable $num is set

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Guessing Game</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to my guessing game</h1>
<form action="" method="GET">
<label for="numinput">Enter your number</label>
<input type="text" name="numinput">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<?php

$num = $_GET['numinput'];


if (!isset($num)) {
    echo("Missing Guess Parameter");}
elseif ( strlen($num) <60){
        echo ("Your guess is too short");}
elseif( !is_numeric($num)){
        echo("Your guess is not a number");}    
elseif ($num > 60){
        echo ("Your guess is too high");}
else{
        echo ("Congratulations - You are right");}
      
?>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Name of the html input and the key of `$_GET` must be identical, so change `name="numinput"` to `name="num"` will be a solution to fixed the problem.

**NB:** `$num = $_GET['num'];` may accure **UNDEFINED INDEX** if you use it outside the `if` condition when `isset($_GET['num'])` equal to `true`

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Guessing Game</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome to my guessing game</h1>
    <form action="" method="GET">
      <label for="numinput">Enter your number</label>
      <input type="text" name="num">
      <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>

<?php
//$num = $_GET['num']; this should be after isset($_GET['num']) == true
if (!isset($_GET['num'])) {
  echo("Missing Guess Parameter");
} elseif ( strlen($_GET['num']) <60){
  echo ("Your guess is too short");
} elseif ( !is_numeric($_GET['num'])){
  echo("Your guess is not a number");
} elseif ($_GET['num'] > 60){
  echo ("Your guess is too high");
} else {
  echo ("Congratulations - You are right");
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```